# Как удалить строку в SQLite, чтобы не удалить "индекс"

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Не смогла корректно ввести запрос в гугл, поэтому пишу сюда

Есть база данных со строками:

```
id - с первичным ключом
gender 
age 
color_hair и тд с данными о пользователях
```

При определенных условиях нужно удалять строки с данными о пользователях, соответственно вместе с ними будет удаляться id с "порядковым номером" пользователя, то есть на старте есть таблица:

```
1 мужской 20 темный
2 женский 15 светлый
3 женский 30 рыжий
```

После удаления второй строки остается:

```
1 мужской 20 темный
3 женский 30 рыжий
```

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы осталось:

```
1 мужской 20 темный
2 женский 30 рыжий
```

Нужно это для того, что внутри программы запускается цикл по id и выполняются определенные операции, соответственно, если ставлю цикл

```
for i in range(len(количество строк))
```

То количество строк остается 2, но присутствует id == 3, не могу c данными работать по id == i

А если сначала получить данные, например, в переменную string о всех строках, а потом их обрабатывать, то:

```
for i in sting
```

Не могу обращаться по id к строкам, а мне это нужно в моей задаче

**Сама задача:**

Есть написанный Telegram-бот, который подбирает кастинги по заданным характеристикам для моделей. Есть таблица с характеристиками моделей, которая заполняется по мере работы пользователя с ботом, есть таблица с кастингами, которую заполняют менеджеры также через бота

Таблицы идентичны по виду, так как заполнение происходит по кнопкам, то есть таблица кастингов выглядит:

```
id (номер кастинга)
casting
gender
age и тд (данные, которые указаны в кастинге)
```

В отдельных строках они, потому что по ним идет сравнение с характеристиками моделей.

Каждые два дня старые кастинги должны удаляться, что и приводит к сдвигу по id (для меня проще называть "порядковому номеру кастинга"), но когда пользователь нажимает кнопку "Найти кастинг", должен сработать цикл, бегущий по всем кастингам, а по id кастинга, который равен счетчику цикла, происходит работа с данными (сверяются на соответствие с данными пользователя)

Бот функционировал ранее без проблем, сейчас просто происходит его улучшение и расширение, в связи с чем столкнулась с необходимостью работать по id, а не по тексту кастинга, как ранее

Не знаю, понятно ли смогла задать вопрос, буду рада помощи!

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А почему нельзя просто убрать id, но по списку проходиться не с помощью `for i in string`, а с помощью `for id in range(len(string))`?

Comment: 1) "Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы осталось:" - можно, но не нужно. Это очень плохая практика. Вы сами пишете, что это первичный ключ, если вы начнете первичные ключи заменять, то все связанные таблицы "поедут". И даже, если таких таблиц нет сейчас, то вы эту возможность навсегда "зарежете". 2) что такое `i` относительно кортежа в `for i in sting`?

Comment: @Сергей i - получаемая строка из всех строк в string, в string запихиваются по данному примеру все строки из таблицы (в данном случае все три). А если убрать первичный ключ и добавлять "руками" номера строк? Просто все равно необходимо удалять строки и потом обращаться к ним по id, неудобно, когда после 1 по id строки будет идти 7, а затем 30 (например)

Comment: @nyekitka а как будет проходить цикл по строкам, где id == 1, 5, 7, 8, 30 и тд с неизвестным разбросом из-за удалений? Ведь если len(string) == 3, и цикл запускается до 3, а там данные с id == 1, 5, 10, то последние два не обработаются, либо я неверно Вас поняла

Comment: Анна, вы решите, что вам нужно. Если вам не нужен первичный ключ, так не делайте лишний столбец. Судя по всему вам с `ROW NUMBER` надо работать (= "добавлять руками"). Идея же все строки поместить сначала в string хорошо выглядит только для учебного примера, полагаю. Но странно звучит "Не могу обращаться по id к строкам, а мне это нужно в моей задаче" - вы бы тогда задачу включили в вопрос хоть для справки, а то похоже на проблему XY.

Comment: @AnnaVelichko а вы ещё выборки будете делать?

Comment: @Сергей я относительно недавно изучаю данную тему, поэтому не со всеми деталями могу быть знакома, спасибо за наводку про row number. Дополнила вопрос информацией о задаче

Comment: @nyekitka да, дополнила для большей ясности информацию о задаче, которую должна выполнить программа

Comment: Анна, 1) Не работал c sqllite и не знаю, как он "живёт" с Python, но как-то странно всё - где вообще язык SQL тут? У вас есть БД. Есть запрос пользователя с параметрами. Зачем бегать по строкам БД циклом, вместо нормального запроса типа 'SELECT id, gender, age FROM name_table WHERE name = "name пользователя" AND age = "age пользователя" (условно).  2) Даже если циклом, то я не очень понимаю, зачем "по id кастинга, который равен счетчику цикла, происходит работа с данными". Подумайте, как получить доступ к `id`, не имея его равным счетчику цикла (может, ROW NUMBER, может проще).

Comment: @AnnaVelichko тогда ещё такой вопрос. Строчки будут удаляться по одной или могут по нескольку (например, как `DELETE FROM table WHERE <какое-то выражение>`)?

Comment: @Сергей бегать по строчкам цикла нужно для сравнения данных, работа так происходит: пользователь заполняет анкету, его данные помещаются в таблицу USERS, он нажимает на кнопку "Найти кастинг", после чего запускается цикл по всем кастингам в бд в таблице CASTING и внутри программы сравниваются данные из строк gender_user (таблица USERS) и gender_casting (таблица CASTING) и тд. Цикл запускается по порядковому номеру, при совпадении всех параметров  (gender, age и тд) отправляется данный кастинг по опять же его порядковому номеру, то есть внутри цикла происходит отправка сообщений

Comment: @nyekitka по одному, но пачками, удаление тоже происходит циклом. Получаю все кастинги по строке "время" (оно записано там как "время записи + 2 дня"), если кастинг старше двух дней, то он удаляется, в день картингов 10-15 публикуют, соответственно цикл по одному 10-15 удаляет за прошедшие дни

Comment: Анна, это понятно. Непонятно, зачем так организовали:-) Но не для дискуссии, просто на "подумать".

Comment: еще как вариант добавить в таблицу поле "порядковый номер" и после каждого удаления записей обновлять это поле (оконной функцией), ну и уже этот номер использовать в вашем цикле.

Comment: _"его данные помещаются в таблицу USERS, он нажимает на кнопку "Найти кастинг", после чего запускается цикл по всем кастингам в бд в таблице CASTING и внутри программы сравниваются данные из строк gender_user (таблица USERS) и gender_casting (таблица CASTING) и тд"_ а почему это не сделать через SELECT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если удаление будет происходить по одному элементу, то тогда это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
#для примера сделаю список из id
ids = [1, 2, 7, 9]
for id in ids:
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM table WHERE id = ?", (id,))
    cursor.execute("UPDATE table SET id = id - 1 WHERE id > ?", (id, ))
    db.commit()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Стоило попробовать Ваш вариант, как додумалась до своего тоже))) Можно перебирать не по id, а по тексту кастинга, как делала это раньше, намудрила кашу! :D Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Анна, вот поэтому я и писал "Даже если циклом, то я не очень понимаю, зачем "по id кастинга, который равен счетчику цикла, происходит работа с данными", так как логики было не видно:-)

Comment: @Сергей видимо нужно было словами написать все, почитать несколько раз и подумать побольше :D